# Is there something wrong with the Graph class of Manim Community v0.5.0?

Tags: graph, manim

I am using last version of Manim Community in Pycharm

This code

```
class MovingVertices(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        vertices = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        edges = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (1, 3), (1, 4)]
        g = Graph(vertices, edges)
```

gives this error :

```
   TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

I am struggling to understand the error. The other examples give the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Solution : I have created a new file called graph.py and export all the code example inside. Maybe the other py files was producing a conflict I can't explain.

Answer (score 0):

Manim 0.7.0 version

```
class MovingVertices(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        vertices = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        edges = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (1, 3), (1, 4)]
        g = Graph(vertices, edges)
        self.play(Create(g))
        self.wait()
```